# How do I turn this javascript code into a function?

Tags: javascript, function, discord.js

CODE -

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js")
const db = require('quick.db')
var today = new Date();
var date = today.getFullYear()+""+(today.getMonth()+1)+today.getDate()+""+ today.getHours()+""+ today.getMinutes()+"" + today.getSeconds()+"" + today.getMilliseconds();

exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {
  
 
db.set(`ticket_${message.author.id}`, date);
  
  let yes = await db.fetch( `ticket_${message.author.id}`, date) || 'error'
  
  message.channel.send(`${yes}`)
```

The time isn't renewing everytime I run the command, But If I put it into a function it Will. How do I turn this piece of code into a function?

Comment: It looks like it already is a function. Move `today` and `date` variables into the exported `run` function. Essentially what is happening is those values are being computed and then enclosed in the function so they are "stuck" with whatever value they were when the function was instantiated and exported.

Answer (score 0):

Your `date` variable is outside of the exported `run` function, simply moving it inside of the `run` function will make it "recalculate" when called.

```
const Discord = require("discord.js")
const db = require('quick.db')

exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {    
    var today = new Date();
    var date = today.getFullYear()+""+(today.getMonth()+1)+today.getDate()+""+today.getHours()+""+ today.getMinutes()+"" + today.getSeconds()+"" + today.getMilliseconds();

    db.set(`ticket_${message.author.id}`, date);

      let yes = await db.fetch( `ticket_${message.author.id}`, date) || 'error'

      message.channel.send(`${yes}`)
```